# Different results using color-theme-select versus color-theme-<theme-name>

Tags: themes, faces, colors

I am using the color-theme package to manage the colors in Emacs 24.3.1.  I used the command `color-theme-select` to try different color themes until I found one that I liked.  In this case I found the Hober theme.  Then I put the following code into my `.emacs` file to automatically load the color theme when I start up emacs.

```
(require 'color-theme)
(setq color-theme-is-global t)
(color-theme-initialize)
(color-theme-hober)
(set-frame-font "lucidatypewriter-9")
```

However, when I reload emacs, the color theme is significantly darker than what I saw before.  Why are the two approaches to selecting the color theme yielding different results?

The following are pictures of the two cases.

If I select via `color-theme-select`:

[image: If I select via <code>color-theme-select</code>:]

If I select via `color-theme-hober` and the other code mentioned above:

[image: If I select via <code>color-theme-hober</code> and the other code mentioned above:]

Comment: It looks like you're using `emacs -nw` and the difference is between the normal and bright colors of your terminal emulator.

Comment: You are correct.  I am connected via ssh using SecureCRT with the emulator xterm.  The difference does appear to be between normal and bright colors for the ANSI color set.  I still do not understand, however, why one command results in the bold/bright colors and one results in the normal colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`color-theme` is an old third-party package which is no longer required since Emacs version 24.1, which comes with built-in support for color themes. In fact loading `color-theme` is going to mess up the built-in support.

So don't load `color-theme` and only use themes which are compatible with the built-in theme functionality. The new themes are named `NAME-theme` while the old ones which can no longer be used usually are named `color-theme-NAME`.